# How to overwrite background color of td of table?

Tags: css

Ok, I got these css & it works fine

```
table td, th{
  padding: 5px;
  border:0px solid black;
  text-align:left; 
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    /* background-color:  #cce5ff; */
    background-color: #F1FCFD;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
    /* background-color:    #ffccff; */
    background-color: #f3f7fb;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) th{
    background-color: #ffcc99;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) tf{
    background-color: none;
}
```

Now I want to clear the background of td
so I did:

```
.noBg{
background-color: none;
}

table.rule2 tr:nth-child(odd) td{
    background-color: none;
}
table.rule2 tr:nth-child(even) td{
    background-color: none;
}



  <table>
        <tr >
        <td colspan="2" class="noBg"><center><input type="submit" value="Login" /></center></td>
        </tr>

<tr >
        <td colspan="2" class="rule2"><center><input type="submit" value="Login" /></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But both solutions does not work!

**SO, How to overwrite background color of td of table?**

Comment: Your `.rule2` is designed as a class of a `table`, but applied to `td`?

Comment: I copied the code elsewhere I have little knowledge about it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the value 'transparent'.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td.rule2{
    background-color: transparent;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td.rule2{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```